# Find where windows program is installed

Tags: windows-10

How can I find the installation directory of a program? The program's uninstaller is not working and I want to remove the files manually. I have tried searching for the programs name in explorer but it does not find anything.

OS: Windows 10

EDIT: I can't find the executable.
EDIT 2: My question is: "How can I find where the uninstaller is?"

Comment: If you have the program in your start menu you could right click -> properties and then look at the application target path? Alternatively might I suggest a [forced un-installation app](http://www.iobit.com/en/advanceduninstaller.php)? You could just try the standard uninstaller via the program and when that fails just do the more powerful  registry and file deletion option.

Comment: Do a search for the executable.  If you created a shortcut to the executable in the past that is the quickest way to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off your comments on the other answer, have you considered looking in your registry under the uninstaller information? If it's only showing in Programs and Features, that should give you a clue what it is and where it might be stored.

- Open Regedit
- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- Look through the entries there to see if one matches the program you are seeing in Programs & Features

For 64-bit windows, you may also need to check under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Also, if you are seeing it in your Start Menu, you could check C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu to see if you can find a shortcut that gives you some clues.

Comment: I found it in the registry by searching for the program's name. It was in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Answer (score 3):

If the program is running, you may open `Task Manager`, and either find the program under `Processes` or under `Details`, then right-click the program and choose `Open File Location`.

Comment: I cannot find the executable

Comment: At this point I'm confused as to how you can even verify the program exists... If you can't find it, or search for it, or run the program, or uninstall it... is it even real?

Comment: I can find it in programs and features. I cannot remember what it is

Comment: So on top of the things I listed in my last comment, you also _don't remember_ what the program is called...? We're entering some realm of obscurity here. I'm not sure what to say... is there an icon for it on your desktop... does it load when you boot into Windows?

Comment: I cannot find it in task manager, it is not on my desktop but I can see it in programs and features. It does not open any windows

Comment: i ve got the path  when expanded its main process from its chld

Answer (score 1):

If the program can be called at the command line, you can use the `where` command.

```
where robocopy

C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
```

Or if it's not in the path but you know it's somewhere - on each drive

```
dir /b /s robocopy.*

C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
C:\Windows\System32\en-US\Robocopy.exe.mui
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Robocopy.exe
```

Don't be a prisoner of the GUI.